# Is there a cleaner way of querying based on another query's result?

Tags: php, mysql

Below I have a working implementation of querying a chosen table, $table, and returning $numRows rows ordered descending by the first column of the table:

```
$cQuery = "SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table' LIMIT 1";

$mysqli = new mysqli( DB_LOCATION , DB_USERNAME , DB_PASSWORD );
 if ( $mysqli -> connect_errno )
     err("Could not connect to DB. " . $mysqli->connect_error);

$result = $mysqli -> query( $cQuery ) -> fetch_array();     
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $result[0] DESC LIMIT $numRows";

$result = $mysqli -> query( $query );
```

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to do this is only one mysqli statement? There has to be two table queries; one for the column ID and a second for the specific query, but does it need to be distinct like I have it?

Any critique is welcome.

Comment: Odd... I read your final query as: Get the top `$numRows` from `$table` ordered by whichever random column_name is returned by the first query. Are you sure it's working?

Comment: @Denis I believe it is working as intended. The first query returns the columns in their ordinal position from what I've experienced, so by limiting the query to 1, it returns only the first row. I could be wrong. Should I specify in the first query?

Comment: The first query returns columns in the order they appear on the disc. You need to specify an explicit `order by` clause in SQL, else the order the rows should get returned in is undefined.

Comment: @Denis In this case it is safe to assume that the order on disk is constant. The database is managed locally, and the first column is always a general ID. However, for good practice I will try to change this anyway. Do you have any suggestions as to how to sort it? common #1 columns are: id, point_id, result_id, etc.

Comment: " it is safe to assume that the order on disk is constant" -- nope, it is not. :) But in your particular case, I'm 99% sure that the view used in the information_schema returns the columns in the order they appear in the table. Just keep this in mind for tables that reside in userland.

Comment: Does it matter that the tables I am querying are view tables?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. The view is probably something like: select a bunch of fields from/join various tables where some criteria order by column position. Without the view's order by clause, you'd be ordering by a random column.

Comment: accessing the information schema is often indicative of poor design. just sayin'

Comment: @denis: to be on the safe side, the query could be written as `SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Strawberry Why is this a poor design? I'd like to know so I can improve in the future. From what I've read, accessing the information schema is the only way to get column positions.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to grab the first column *name* for a table from the database schema so that you can use it in an `ORDER BY` clause. You don't *really* have to specify the column name in order by clause, you can specify the ordinal position:

```
SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY 1 DESC ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just use a subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.$table ORDER BY (
    SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table' LIMIT 1) DESC
  LIMIT $numRows";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: This orders by a criteria which is a varchar (the column's name). Won't work.